# Unity logs out after logging back in from suspend

Tags: xorg

I'm having an issue. It's even repeatable by opening and closing my laptop to force suspends. After logging in 20 seconds to a few mins latter, Unity will log out. Upon logging back in, all of my programs are closed. No idea where to start with the error log. Suggestions? I looked at link to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9284198#post9284198 I didn't see where it was helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my `.xsession-errors.old`:

```
ackend : gconf Integration : true Profile : unity Adding plugins Initializing core options...done Initializing composite options...done Initializing opengl options...done Initializing decor options...done Initializing vpswitch options...done Initializing snap options...done Initializing mousepoll options...done Initializing resize options...done Initializing place options...done Initializing move options...done Initializing wall options...done ** Message: applet now removed from the notification area Initializing grid options...done I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/erick/.compiz/session/10d797861e1335917c134317912576374900000021050033" Initializing session options...done Initializing gnomecompat options...done Initializing animation options...done Initializing fade options...done ** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done Initializing workarounds options...done Initializing scale options...done compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture Initializing expo options...done Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:2173): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed Initializing unityshell options...done Setting Update "main_menu_key" Setting Update "run_key" Setting Update "autohide_animation" ** Message: moving back from GtkStatusIcon to indicator

** (zeitgeist-datahub:2638): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!

** (gnome-screensaver:2639): WARNING **: screensaver already running in this session [2426:2537:50442055:ERROR:download_updates_command.cc(99)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates [2426:2537:52443452:ERROR:download_updates_command.cc(99)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates

** (nautilus:2195): WARNING **: Error calling current_status: Method "current_status" with signature "" on interface "com.ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Status" doesn't exist

** (nautilus:2195): CRITICAL **: syncdaemon_status_info_get_online: assertion `SYNCDAEMON_IS_STATUS_INFO (sinfo)' failed [2426:2537:57445240:ERROR:download_updates_command.cc(99)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates [2426:2537:61716091:ERROR:download_updates_command.cc(99)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates [2426:2537:69717992:ERROR:download_updates_command.cc(99)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates [2426:2537:81720581:ERROR:download_updates_command.cc(99)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture

(bluetooth-applet:2190): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(bluetooth-applet:2190): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent. compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture

(bluetooth-applet:2190): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(bluetooth-applet:2190): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(bluetooth-applet:2190): Gdk-WARNING **: bluetooth-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

gnome-session[2105]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(nm-applet:2198): Gdk-WARNING **: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(gnome-fallback-mount-helper:2191): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-fallback-mount-helper: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(nautilus:2195): Gdk-WARNING **: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:2192): Gdk-WARNING **: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(gnome-settings-daemon:2152): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

gtk-window-decorator: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0. [4600:4600:911100154:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_x11.cc(62)] X IO Error detected

(telepathy-indicator:2572): Gdk-WARNING **: telepathy-indicator: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(gdu-notification-daemon:2422): Gdk-WARNING **: gdu-notification-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(update-notifier:2724): Gdk-WARNING **: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(gnome-terminal:4761): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-terminal: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :0.

thunderbird: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

(deja-dup-monitor:3384): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner :1.29 of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.GduVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts

(deja-dup-monitor:3384): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner :1.31 of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts

(deja-dup-monitor:3384): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner :1.32 of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
```

Comment: Not really a solution but a quick fix, have you disable resume?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this launchpad bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/587136

Look at comment [#3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/587136/comments/3) and follow the steps.

You can click on "This bug affects 2 people. Does this bug affect you?", and get it registered.